# optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function in LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I'd like to optimize my queries. This query is too slow for my server.

Is there any solution for this issue?
Thanks!

```
SELECT *,TABLE.id AS identyfikator 
FROM TABLE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TWO ON TABLE.code = TABLE_TWO.code 
WHERE TABLE_TWO.city = $ID 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Try using col names instead of '*'.

Comment: Use explain to get the execution plan. But in those cases usually ORDER BY RAND() is the culprit.

Comment: Because of `WHERE TABLE_TWO.city = $ID`, I see no point in using `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Karolis Missed that. Of course it will change the left join to an inner join.

Comment: How large are the two tables?

Comment: What are your indexes? Do you have indexes on TABLE_TWO(city) and TABLE(code)? How large is the result set? Since you're returning all columns, show your schema.

Answer (score 0):

you can separate order by and limit so that it can be fast

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        TABLE.id AS identyfikator 
    FROM TABLE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TWO ON TABLE.code = TABLE_TWO.code 
    WHERE TABLE_TWO.city = $ID 
) m 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I think MySQL will already perform the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` after the join. How will this improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index on code column of both the tables.